# Remembering Position of LongListSelector

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I'm developing a Windows Phone 7 (WP7) app and I'm using a LongListSelector control for a list.  When the user taps on one of the items, my event handler navigates to a new page for the selected item.  However, when the user clicks on the back button to return to the previuos page, the LongListSelector is at a different position than it was.  Does anyone know how to remember the position of the selector and restore that position when it is returned to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you handle the `SelectionChanged` event, you can save the `SelectedItem` (which I assume you are already retrieving in order to determine the new page) to a page property.  Then in the `OnNavigatedTo` event for the page, if that item is not null then you can use the `ScrollTo` Method.  Something like this (Where `lls` is your longlistselector):

```
private object previousItem = null;
private void lls_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    object previousItem = lls.SelectedItem;
    //Page Navigation Magic
}

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    if (previousItem != null)
        lls.ScrollTo(previousItem);
}
```